# CondaHTTPError in Windows Powershell

Tags: conda

When trying to create a new environment with conda (`conda create -n myenv`) I get the following error in windows powershell.

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2
Elapsed: -
```

I checked: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8046 but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem turned out to be related to powershell.

After running: `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` in an admin powershell and restarting the error was gone.